# Scrollbar thumb is displayed over an absolute div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, tailwind-css

So I have the situation that is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

There is a calendar that open when a button is clicked, the div container for the calendar is absolutely positioned. But the scrollbar of the underneath table is always on top of that calendar, the calendar has a very high `z-index` already.

The table has `overflow` set to `auto`.

I tried targeting the scrollbar with some custom CSS to manipulate the z-index but that made the whole scrollbar disappear:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
     z-index: -1;
}
```

Also tried `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` and `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` which had no effect. Any idea what I can try? Thanks.

P.S. I'm using VueJs with Tailwind.

Comment: pls share code.. html and css

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `z-index` of calendar like `999`

```
.your_calendar_class{
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried positioning the parent container of the calendar div?

Answer (score 0):

add your css "position" tag.

```
.your_calendar_class{
   z-index: 999;  
}
```

this doesn't work.

use:

```
.your_calendar_class{
   z-index: 999;  
   position:relative;
}
```